# What is batch file equivalent in Mac to move all files with .dat extension to another folder in a usb drive

Tags: macos, bash, terminal

I need to create a script to move all the files with certain extension from root of USB1 to specificFolder.

So far I have created a move.command file with this code

```
#!/bin/bash
mv /VOLUMES/USB1/*.dat /VOLUMES/USB1/specificFolder
```

and I am setting x bit on the file to make it executable with

```
chmod +x move.command
```

When I double click the file to launch, terminal opens up and this message is displayed
/Volumes/USB1/move.command ; exit;
logout
[Process completed]

But files are not moved over. 
What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

In case somebody needs this: I solved the problem by using .sh file instead of .command file and just using this piece of code in the file

```
mv /VOLUMES/USB1/*.dat /VOLUMES/USB1/specificFolder
```

First line with /bin/bash was not needed.
Also note that the file extension is case sensitive, this command only moved .dat files and not .DAT files.